# LINQ professional query for WebMethod

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

```
Global entity: {  WorkerId , ProjId, Date }
Worker entity: { Workerid, WorkerName }
Project entity: { ProjId, ProjName }
New Projects entity : { ProjId, ProjInf }
```

The WebMethod needs to recieve a date and to return:

```
>WorkerName
>how many projects he has // count Project entity with WorkerId 
>how many new projects he has // count New Projects entity with ProjId, we know wich ProjId needs to be count for the worker from the Global entity
```

Please help me with building a Linq query for this...I cannot find any solutions all over google

Comment: Please post more information in future. Proper explanation of the Entity Relationships of your entities and same code of what you have tried so far (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can guess at without knowing more about your Entity Model:

```
var results =
  objectContext.Global
  .Where(g => g.Date == dateTimeParam)
  .Select(
    g =>
      new
      {
         WorkerName = g.Worker.Name,
         ProjectCount = g.Worker.Projects.Count(),
         NewProjectCount = g.Worker.NewProjects.Count(),
      });
```

Comment: thank you please see what i wrote based on your code

Comment: I would open a new question based on the error you are having, now that you have a code sample, and a specific problem.